# printdocument printing issue only prints first page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I have to be able to print all the items in a ListView in order with the column name like so:

Start: (date)
End: (date)
Shift: (shift number)
Sales:  (sales)

and it prints perfectly for what I need but it only prints the first page (or first 12 rows of the listview.  However if I send the information to a message box it sends all the listview contents so its in the printing that's causing it not to print all of it but I can not figure it out.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            PrintDocument MyPrintDocument = new PrintDocument();
            MyPrintDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintPageEvent);
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages;
            MyPrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages;
            MyPrintDocument.Print();
        }
}


 private void PrintPageEvent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
     {
        string text = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView4.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            text += "Start: " + listView4.Items[i].Text + Environment.NewLine + "End: " + listView4.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + Environment.NewLine + "Shift Number: " + listView4.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + Environment.NewLine + "Total Sales: " + listView4.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text + Environment.NewLine + "----------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(text);
        Font MyFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
        ev.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------" +
    Environment.NewLine + text +
    Environment.NewLine + "------------------------------------", MyFont, new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black),
            (ev.PageBounds.Left), ev.PageBounds.Top);
       }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You'll need bigger paper or use the e.HasMorePages property.  Which also requires you to continue printing where you left off on the previous page.  In other words, your `i` variable needs to be a class member and you need BeginPrint to reset it to 0.  An iterator is a nice way to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign `PrintPageEventArgs.HasMorePages = true` to print multiple pages. So , in your case, you will simply do it like this

```
ev.HasMorePages = true;
```

`PrintPageEventArgs.HasMorePages` Property -

- gets or sets a value indicating whether an additional page should be printed.
- returns `true` if an additional page should be printed; otherwise, `false`
- The default is `false`.

Comment: I have read about this but the problem is I dont know where to put that I put it at the end and it just keeps printing rows 1 - 12 over and over and over.

Comment: When I set this flag its spools over and over again on the printer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `e.HasMorePages = true;` when you have more pages to print inside the `PrintPageEvent` method handler. According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages.aspx) the default is `false`.